# How to specify a property path in an attribute constructor without using strings directly

Tags: c#, attributes

I'm building a business rule engine and I'd like to add attribute decorations to the rules that will define the property the rule will apply to. I'd like to be able to define the path in dot notation instead of using strings.

```
[RunRuleOn(MapPath<SomeObject>(p=>p.SomeProperty))]
public class MyRule
{
...
}
```

I found a [good idea](https://josefottosson.se/get-dot-notation-of-c-sharp-property-member/) for mapping the path using an expression, but the attribute constructor throws the error: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

I don't want to use the form:
`[RunRuleOn("SomeObject.SomeProperty")]`
I'd rather make it fail at compile time.

Edit:
Final (simplified) Attribute Implementation:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class RunRuleOnAttribute : Attribute
{
    public RunRuleOnAttribute(Type model, string property = null)
    {
        Path = model.Name;
        if (property != null)
        {
            Path += $".{property}";
            HasProperty = true;
        }
    }

    public string Path { get; }
    public bool HasProperty { get; } = false;
}
```

Usage: `[RunRuleOn(typeof(SomeObject), nameof(SomeObject.SomeProperty))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# 6.0 introduced a new operator named, **nameof** that accepts the name of code element and returns a string literal of the same element.  The **nameof** operator can take as a parameter like class name and its all members like method, variables, properties and return the string literal.  This avoids having hardcoded strings to be specified in our code as well as avoid explicitly use of reflection to get the names. 
You can use:

```
[RunRuleOn(nameof(SomeObject.SomeProperty))]
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to get **[ClassName]**.**[ProeprtyName]** you should use:

```
[RunRuleOn(nameof(Product) + "." + nameof(Product.Title))]
```

Comment: that only results in "someproperty"

Comment: @Bacon, fixed  !

Comment: I ended up using something similar [RunRuleOn(typeof(SomeType), nameof(SomeType.SomeProperty))] - Thanks! (edited for typo)